# Am I understanding this Storm King's Thunder map wrong?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, maps, storm-kings-thunder

My group will soon be finished with *Lost Mine of Phandelver*, and I've been told *Storm King's Thunder* is a great next campaign to run.

I am currently building maps in Roll20 and noticed that in one map particularly, Beorunna's Well, says that each grid square is 50 feet.

**Can someone please tell me if I'm misreading that map?**

If that's correct, then everything in that map is insanely huge compared to my 5 sq ft players and means it would take nearly 2 rounds of movement to traverse a single grid.

Comment: I allowed my group to descend their airship into the Well, and they chose to land on the water, and were then promptly attacked by ... that thing living in the water.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## You are reading the map correctly.

The [Beorunna's Well](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/skt/the-savage-frontier#BeorunnasWell) map and description appear on p. 76-77 of the adventure book.

Here is the DM's version of the map from the adventure on D&D Beyond:

[image: Beorunna's Well map]

The scale listed there matches the one mentioned in your post: each square on the grid is 50 feet. This is further supported by the descriptive text about the altar:

> **The altar is a blood-spattered stone block, 9 feet long by 6 feet wide by 3 feet tall, weighing several tons.** A creature as big and strong as a stone giant can move it, as can multiple Small or Medium creatures if at least five of them succeed on a DC 20 Strength (Athletics) check. [...] Beneath the altar is a rough-hewn niche containing the skeletal remains of a half-ogre and a relic of giantkind: a fossilized horn made from the tusk of a mammoth and engraved with images of giants battling dragons.

The features of the map do not seem to be drawn perfectly to scale, but the nearly 10-foot-long altar takes up less then half a square on the grid. Given what's under the altar, it would necessarily have to be quite large to fit such things below it.

The SKT adventure hasn't received any errata, so the map's legend is presumably correct (i.e. as the designers intended).

Comment: It's worth noting that this isn't the only map in premade campaigns that uses a larger scale. OP seems to be confused because he's trying to use it as a battle map, but that's not really what it's intended for, it's more of an overview map, much like the city and village maps you can find in D&D 5e campaigns.

Comment: Our DM did not realize this either and ended up just scaling our tokens up on roll20 but it was super weird still.